# Error when creating spark cluster in Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I'm trying to create a Spark cluster with Amazon EMR

```
aws emr create-cluster --name SparkCluster --ami-version 3.2 --instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 3 --ec2-attributes KeyName=[[MYKEY_VALUE]] --applications Name=Hive --bootstrap-actions Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark
```

Substituting [[MYKEY_VALUE]] with my access key id from amazon.

When I run

```
aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id CLUSTER-ID-HERE
```

I get this

```
"Cluster": {
        "Status": {
            "Timeline": {
                "EndDateTime": 1431824191.597, 
                "CreationDateTime": 1431824149.281
            }, 
            "State": "TERMINATED_WITH_ERRORS", 
            "StateChangeReason": {
                "Message": "The given SSH key name was invalid", 
                "Code": "VALIDATION_ERROR"
            }
```

What should I do to turn the status into WAITING?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check the key that you have provided while creating the cluster ?

it his key pair exists ? . You can check the key pair in AWS console.

```
KeyName=[[MYKEY_VALUE]]
```

Comment: I didn't use any key pair. I just used the access key id, which I found Security Credentials -> Access Keys Where should I use the key_pair.pem?

Comment: KeyName is _not_ the access key but is the EC2 key pair used for SSH access. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

Comment: In AWS console ,under EC2 you will find key-pairs. You need to give that key pair while creating the cluster